# Forced movement in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm currently trying to make time lapses in skyrim but i can't find a way to keep my player moving left, right or backwards like when you press the C key and continually run forward.
Are there any console commands that will keep me moving without any external input or do i have to weigh down a key?

Comment: I guess you could try mapping one of these movements to the caps lock key, as a workaround.

Comment: I’m not aware of any console commands that will do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could just map the movement to a key that you can toggle e.g. Caps lock, Num lock, Scroll lock, etc. That way you don't have to weigh anything down. And as far as I'm aware, there are no console commands in Skyrim that are able to produce this effect. In case there are any, you can try looking [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console_Commands).

Comment: For a better result, you change your movement speed using `player.setav speedmult x`.